# Selecting a whole database over an individual table to output to file

Tags: mysql, file-io

Ok Im having trouble finding out how to select a full database for backup as an *.sql file rather than only an individual table.

On the localhost I have several databases with one named "foo" and it is that which I want to backup and not any of the individual tables inside the database "foo".

The code to connect to the database;

```
//Database Information
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "foo";
$dbuser = "bar";
$dbpass = "rulz";

//Connect to database
mysql_connect ($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)
    or die("Could not connect: ".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());
```

The code to backup the database, one question I have with this is where do I set were the *.gz file is saved?

```
$backupFile = $dbname . date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") . '.gz';
$command = "mysqldump --opt -h $dbhost -u $dbuser -p $dbpass $dbname | gzip
            > $backupFile";
system($command);
```

My brain is hurting near to the end of the day so no doubts i've missed something out very obvious.

Thanks in advance to anyone helping me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've missed [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)! Its a command line utility designed specifically for what you are trying to do.

Writing a backup file manually is rather hard. Writing one that you will consistently be able to recover from is **very** hard. Check out the docs, it has a lot of options that you can use to specify what exactly you want to save.

Comment: Hahaha +1! I was typing the exact same thing. Exact same words. And then the dreaded "1 other answer has been posted"...

Comment: You've missed an explanation as to what that is and why it should be used :(

Comment: Click on the link, it will tell you all about it.

Comment: I have, but techno geeks never write anything in plain english, I was really hoping for an example using my code I posted, as per the norm from the SO community :(

Comment: @Mat: nah, he is right: you should explain in a few words what it does, and why re-inventing it might be silly. However, a lot of programmers write code that uses mysqldump itself, for each table or for treating the .sql files afterwards.

Comment: mysqldump is a command line utility. You don't need any code around it, except some wrapper code if you absolutely need to call it from a script. Trying to do create a backup-like file is actually rather complicated business (think about quoting for instance) unless you don't actually plan on restoring it. mysqldump takes care of all the details for you, and has options for dump only the data, only the metadata, both, and lots more. You should use that IMO, or use the other built-in backup features of your DBMS.

Comment: Thank you very much Mat & Konerak, I do appreciate the insight. I am going to edit the OP to show what I have for the mysqldump script.